# Импорт данных из excel

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql, excel

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать импорт в существующую таблицу postgresql из excel файла. Через java код

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24278477/insert-excel-data-to-database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно попробовать такую реализацию:

````java
Можно попробовать такую реализацию:

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;

public class Insert {
    public static void main( String [] args ) {
        String fileName="C:\\File.xls";
        Vector dataHolder=read(fileName);
        saveToDatabase(dataHolder);
    }
    
    public static Vector read(String fileName) {
        Vector cellVectorHolder = new Vector();
        
        try {
            FileInputStream myInput = new FileInputStream(fileName);
                POIFSFileSystem myFileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(myInput);
                HSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new HSSFWorkbook(myFileSystem);
                HSSFSheet mySheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);
            Iterator rowIter = mySheet.rowIterator(); 
            
            while(rowIter.hasNext()) {
              HSSFRow myRow = (HSSFRow) rowIter.next();
              Iterator cellIter = myRow.cellIterator();
              Vector cellStoreVector=new Vector();
              
              while(cellIter.hasNext()) {
                  HSSFCell myCell = (HSSFCell) cellIter.next();
                  cellStoreVector.addElement(myCell);
              }
              
              cellVectorHolder.addElement(cellStoreVector);
          }
        } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        
        return cellVectorHolder;
    }
    
    private static void saveToDatabase(Vector dataHolder) {
        String username="";
        String password="";
        
        for (int i=0;i<dataHolder.size(); i++) {
            Vector cellStoreVector=(Vector)dataHolder.elementAt(i);
            for (int j=0; j < cellStoreVector.size();j++) {
                HSSFCell myCell = (HSSFCell)cellStoreVector.elementAt(j);
                String st = myCell.toString();
                username=st.substring(0,1);
                password=st.substring(0);
            }
            
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root", "root");
                Statement stat=con.createStatement();
                int k=stat.executeUpdate("insert into login(username,password) value('"+username+"','"+password+"')");
                System.out.println("Data is inserted");
                stat.close();
                con.close();
            } catch(Exception e) {}
        }
    }
}
````